# How to change content in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am working on a quiz app where I have a screen which holds the number of questions in a table view. When I click on a question it will navigate to other view controller and show the question with options. Now in that view controller I have a next button. What I want is when I tap on that button I want to change the question and options with the next question. I have no idea how to achieve that. Any help..

I am sharing the screenshot of the screens.

[image]

Also, I wasn't sure about the question title so if someone knows what should be the right title then please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store questions and answers in an array or dictionary or custom data type as-

```
struct data {
     let question: String
     let op1: String
     let op2: String
     let op3: String
     let op4: String
}
```

then create array in the other viewcontroller class as -

```
var allData = [data]()
```

then populate allData.
After that when you click the next button just increase the index number and reload the view controller. That will show the next question on the same viewcontroller.